# Animate element by dragging another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Here's a scenario: I'm trying to implement a joystick using jquery draggable() and base on the y-coordinate of my joystick, i'll move a div to the left or right (if y is positive, move to right; else if y is negative, move to left). I have already done this part but my problem is when to stop the animation.

example;

1. if i drag the joystick upward/downward and hold, the div should not stop moving. it should only stop when i release the joystick. how can i achieve this? i had tried adding this:

   `stop: function(){ $(div).stop() } //should stop animation`
2. and how do i stop the queueing of events?

any suggestions? or someone who could point where i went wrong? thanks.

i created a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/j3toxicat3d/cKd8k/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `.clearQueue`.

```
stop: function(){ $(div).clearQueue() }
```

Each drag is queueing up more animations so they go one after another. The `fast` keyword for speed is 200ms, so the longer it adds up, the longer this will go since `stop` only stops the current animation.

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/cKd8k/3/

Moving some of the functionality outside the drag stuff.

Comment: thanks mate. it does stop the queueing. now problem #1 is all that's left.

Comment: Updated your fiddle to take care of both issues. Link in my edit.